# Cannot display a plotly heatmap in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to display a heatmap I've made in plotly in my shiny app. I *think* the issue may be that I've saved it as an object.. but I don't know how else to display 2 different plots, one made in ggplot and the other in plotly.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(DT) 
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
library(shinythemes)
library(plotly)

#load indel histogram
Indel_histogram <- read.table(file = 'histogram.tsv', 
                              sep = '\t', header = TRUE)

#load peddy relatedness data
Relatedness <-  read.csv(file='peddy/mystudy.ped_check.csv')

###########################
# make relatedness matrix #
###########################

related_matrix <- Relatedness %>% select(sample_a, sample_b, rel)

#make comparison matrix
un2 <- sort(unique(unlist(related_matrix[1:2])))
out2_new <- related_matrix %>% 
  complete(sample_a = un2, sample_b = un2) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = sample_b, values_from = rel)

tmp <- map2_dfc(data.table::transpose(out2_new, make.names = 'sample_a'), 
                out2_new[-1], coalesce) %>% 
  bind_cols(out2_new %>%
              select(sample_a), .)

tmp2 <- column_to_rownames(tmp, var = "sample_a")

#heatmap in plotly format
heatmap %<>% as.matrix(tmp2)

#plot heatmap using plotly
plotly_heatmap <- plot_ly(z = heatmap, type = "heatmap")

#generate indel histogram
Indel_Histogram <- ggplot(Indel_histogram, aes(Length, Freq)) + geom_col()

##################
# Make Shiny App #
##################

ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("united"),
        titlePanel("QC output"),
          navbarPage("Menu",
            tabPanel("Plots",
              sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                  selectInput("more_plots", "Select Plot",
                  choices = c("Indel_Histogram","plotly_heatmap")), width=4),
                            mainPanel(plotOutput("more_plots"), height="100%", width=8))
                           )))

server <- function(input, output) {
 
  
  output$more_plots <- renderPlot({
    get(input$more_plots)
  }, height=600)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

My code shows the `Indel_histogram` no problem, but is does not show the `plotly_heatmap`. If I run `plotly_heatmap` in my Rconsole, it displays for me... so I need help to get both the histogram and the heatmap to view in the same panel, when selected from the same `input$moreplots`.

The histogram works fine, so won't bother with that data. Here's a shortened version of `heatmap`:

```
structure(c(NA, -0.03991, -0.0249, -0.01788, -0.02618, -0.03991, 
NA, -0.03303, 0.01615, 0.01119, -0.0249, -0.03303, NA, 0.009972, 
0.01122, -0.01788, 0.01615, 0.009972, NA, 0.01927, -0.02618, 
0.01119, 0.01122, 0.01927, NA), .Dim = c(5L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("AD001", "AD002", "AD003", "AD004", "AD005"), c("AD001", 
    "AD002", "AD003", "AD004", "AD005")))
```

I then tried to render the plotly heatmap separately just to see if I could get it working... but again, doesn't display (not sure why)?

```
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("united"),
                titlePanel("QC output"),
                navbarPage("Menu",
                           tabPanel("Plots",
                                    sidebarLayout(
                                      sidebarPanel(
                                        selectInput("Plotly", "Select Plot",
                                                    choices = "heatmap"), width=4),
                                      mainPanel(plotlyOutput("Plotly"), height="100%", width=8)),
                           )))

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$Plotly <- renderPlotly(
    plot_ly(z = ~get(input$Plotly), type = "heatmap")
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Something is clearly going wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have already created `histogram` and `heatmap` either outside `ui` or insider `server` function, you can try this

```
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("united"),
        titlePanel("QC output"),
          navbarPage("Menu",
            tabPanel("Plots",
              sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                  selectInput("more_plots", "Select Plot",
                               choices = c("Indel_Histogram","plotly_heatmap")), width=4),
                mainPanel(uiOutput("myplot"), height="100%", width=8)
              )
                           )))

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$hist <- renderPlot({
    Indel_Histogram  ##  assuming you already did this histogram 
  })
  
  output$heat <- renderPlotly({
    plotly_heatmap  ## assuming you already have this heatmap
  })
  
  output$myplot <- renderUI({
    if (input$more_plots=="Indel_Histogram"){
      plot <- plotOutput("hist", height=600)
    }else plot <- plotlyOutput("heat")
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Awesome, it works! Just a small edit, it doesn't like `height=600` ... but aside from that it works beautifully.

Comment: Height was from your code.  I would put the height as `plotOutput("hist", height=600)`

Comment: Yep, I figured it out :-)